# Dynamically insert threshold-lines into a d3.js bar chart depending on entered value

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have created a bar chart that parses data from a csv-file. It works great.
I hard-coded 3 lines into the chart that show three thresholds: 0%, 100% and 200%.

In this case, the 3 thresholds represent the following values where 163 is the max. value that only can be decreased. 3, 4, 4,5 stay always the same.

```
0% --> 163 x 3 = 489
100% --> 163 x 4 = 652
200% --> 163 x 4,5 = 733,5
```

Threshold values on the y-axis in the default (max.) state are therefore those:

```
489
652
733,5
```

I am trying now to dynamically insert those 3 lines depending on this one value that can be entered through a field below the graph / or a slider that can be thrown down or to the left. I think a slider would be the better option.

For example, the default and max. value in the field (or on the slider) is 163. Depending on this value my threshold lines have the following values on the y-axis:

```
threshold-line 1: 163 x 3 = 489 --> located at y-axis
threshold-line 2: 163 x 4 = 652 --> located at y-axis
threshold-line 3: 163 x 4,5 = 733,5 --> located at y-axis
```

Now, the 163 is cleaned and a value below 163 is entered (if a value above 163 is entered, error message appears). Or, the better option: default slider position is at max. right side with 163. All three threshold lines have the their default position.

Now, let´s assume, the value is decreased to let´s say 156. All three threshold lines change their y-axis based position according to the new values:

```
threshold-line 1: 156 x 3 = 468 --> new position located at y-axis
threshold-line 2: 156 x 4 = 624 -->  new position located at y-axis
threshold-line 3: 156 x 4,5 = 702 --> new position located at y-axis
```

I want the bars in the chart to have a relative position to the threshold lines, so that the chart-scale adapts automatically. Bars and Lines must always be visible within the scale.

I´ve created a **CODEPEN** to make it more clear, here it is: https://codepen.io/robx360/pen/rERWYv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a codepen with dynamically created thresholds.

https://codepen.io/dan-delaney/pen/agxZJr

To do this, the main thing was reading the value from the input field.

The dynamic slider reads the value and on change calls the graph to redraw itself.  Ideally, this would be split out so that the graph can be redrawn without reading the data from the network again.

Once this value was read, I checked the 200% value against the domain on the Y-axis to see if it would fit.  If not, the Y-axis was set to 110% of the value of the 200% line (to make sure it looked ok), ie;

```
maxVal = +d3.select('#maxVal').text();
if ( maxVal * 4.5 > y.domain()[1]) {
  y.domain([0,maxVal*4.5*1.1]);
}
```

Dynamically adding each line and the text label was achieved by creating an object with each threshold:

```
var thresholds = {
  v0: maxVal*3, //489
  v1: maxVal*4, //652
  v2: maxVal*4.5 //733.5
}
```

Then, using those values to create the lines, and text label:

```
// Draw the line for the first threshold
svg.append("line")
  .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v0))
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v0));

// Draw the label for the first threshold
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "myText")
  .attr("x", width + 2)
    .attr("y", y(thresholds.v0))
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
    .text("0% ≈ " + thresholds.v0.toFixed(2));
```

Hope this helps